# Google Maps Can I get tiles?

Tags: google-maps, user-interface, maps, tiles-game

I want to dynamically create a map but in the same/similar UI to Google maps. Is there a place to get tiles that I can use? An example: [enter link description here](http://www.ccis-calgary.ab.ca/uploads/images/Google_Map_May_2011.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Street Map is a place where you can download the map data.

www.openstreetmap.org

gmap catcher can save tiles from it: https://code.google.com/p/gmapcatcher/

Comment: Interesting, maybe I can work with this. I have the data I just want to construct maps in the same UI using my own data. I wanted to avoid drawing the roads, parks, etc myself. Looking for graphical assets

Comment: I am using gmap catcher (can save from google too i believe) on my Open Pandora, and have to save differen level of zooming seperatly. This means probably that it saves the image tiles, not the data. If the links realy helps you, please don't forget to mark this question as answered^^